# How to stop wp_postmeta from being called on archive and search pages?

Tags: post-meta, meta-query, optimization

Currently, when I load a search or result page, it queries the `wp_postmeta` table which is leading to the page taking ages to load. I realise this is a result of this table being huge (70k rows), and because of how much data is loaded into the cache.

Is there a way to stop `update_post_caches` from being called when these pages are loaded, and then send custom (and more efficient) queries to the database once the template has been loaded?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'customize_query');
function customize_query($query) {
    if($query->is_main_query() && ($query->is_search() || $query->is_archive()) {
        $query->set('update_post_meta_cache', false);
        $query->set('update_post_term_cache', false);
    }
}
```

Then wordpress will make 2 less queries for those pages & then you can use the $wpdb object to write custom queries.

Comment: +1 Good answer! I just want to add that the reason we call `is_main_query` first is so as not to have effect on other things like nav menu and comment queries. Its not always clear why we do that for those that wish to know.

Comment: It doesn't affect comment queries anyway, but yes for nav menu & also if you create `WP_Query` object in your template files/widgets etc.

Comment: Comment widget is what I should have said, very good point about WP_Query objects too.

Comment: nope, anything related to comments has a separate filter `pre_get_comments`